# Are there complicated cases of Linear systems over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

In a maths oral test report , i read a mention explaining a discussion about linear systems on Z could be done (in the context it’s something deep or complicated to treat) and I just don’t understand the complexity ,
Considering a linear System on Z , sure we don’t get any multiplicative inverse except from -1 and 1 but can’t we just discuss about solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ and say : if there is a unique on R , if all the composant of the solution vector are integers then we have a unique solution on Z (and if one composant is not an integer then no solution) , if no solution on R then no solution on Z , and finally if there is an infinity of solutions on R then we must proceed to an independant discussion about if some solutions depending of parameters can be in Z.
I’m also interested about some sources if there are some deepest understanding to have.

Comment: Compare this with linear programming over the reals (which is a polynomial time problem) and over the integers (which is NP hard).

Comment: "we must proceed to an independant discussion about if some solutions depending of parameters can be in Z" This part can be extremly difficult.

Comment: Just consider the problem $(3, 5) \cdot (x, y) = 1$. Over the reals, there are many easy ways to solve this, for example we could take $(x, y) = (1/3, 0)$. Over the integers, we are now attempting instead to do something like the Extended Euclidean algorithm to write $(3, 5) \cdot (-3, 2) = 1$, proving that the GCD of $3$ and $5$ is equal to $1$. GCDs never enter when considering solutions over $\mathbb{R}$. Solving linear systems over the integers has a much more discrete or combinatorial flavour. There are linear systems $Ax = b$ which have solutions over $\mathbb{R}$ but not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Even if saying thanks is unappreciated here , thanks a lot